# Equation to Find Local Minima of a Sinusoidal Function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I want to find the local minima of this equation $$\sin^2\left(\dfrac{33}{x}\pi\right)+\sin^2(x\pi)=y$$ However, I want to know if there is an equation (or several equations) that describe all local minima (including roots).

Comment: How about $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: I'm just looking how to find all local minima. Any method is welcome.

Comment: Just one doubt, is it $\sin^2(\frac{33\pi}{x})$ or $\sin(\frac{33\pi}{x})^2$ ?

Comment: They both mean the same thing @Ak19

Comment: @QuoteDave The first means $[\sin(y)]^2$, the second is $\sin(y^2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering  $$y=\sin\left(\dfrac{33}{x}\pi\right)^2+\sin(x\pi)^2$$ as said in comments, no roots.

Concerning the extrema, taking derivatives
$$y'=2 \pi  \sin (\pi  x) \cos (\pi  x)-\frac{66 \pi  \sin \left(\frac{33 \pi }{x}\right)
   \cos \left(\frac{33 \pi }{x}\right)}{x^2}=\pi  \left(\sin (2 \pi  x)-\frac{33 \sin \left(\frac{66 \pi }{x}\right)}{x^2}\right)$$ So, assuming $x \neq 0$, the extrema (they are infinitely many) are given the the zero's of the equation
$$x^2 \sin (2 \pi  x)=33 \sin \left(\frac{66 \pi }{x}\right)$$ which is transcendental and then would require numerical methods (remember the equation $x=\cos(x)$ does not show explicit solutions).

If $x_n$ denotes the solutions, for very large $n$, they will be closer and closer to the solutions of $\sin(2\pi x)=0$ which are multiples of half integers.

Comment: I think you accidentally multiplied that middle expression by $x^2$

Comment: @BadrB. Thanks for pointing !

Comment: Thank you @ClaudeLeibovici but 1. I change the question to better fit my request and and 2. I'm only interested in minima.

Comment: Also @ClaudeLeibovici I also want to include the roots.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: how can you make $y=0$?

Comment: I believe that would be to find the factors of $33$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Those are not the only local minima.

Comment: No @Andrei but, the answer asked for the roots.